# PDF-Viewer на Qt

Tags: c++, qt, pdf

Задача - создать простой PDF-viewer или конвертировать PDF страницы в QImage.

QtPDF модуль, как я понимаю, на Qt6 не ставится.

Poppler не получается ставить. Пытаюсь собрать сборку, но выдает сотни ошибок. Где я могу найти инструкцию по сборке и установке Poppler на Qt6 (недавно начал изучать, хобби), Windows, MinGW, CMake? Может где-нибудь есть готовые библиотеки для скачивания?

Весь интернет перерыл, но не нашёл ничего. В других форумах даже искал платную помощь по данной теме. Никто не отозвался. Неужели это такая трудная задача?

Comment: QtPDF  должен ставиться. По крайней мере, на 6.4 - все десктопные платформы. Нужен под андроид?

Comment: Qt 6.0 - был недоделанный. (Многих модулей нехватало.) Возможно, в этом дело.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

QtPDF интегрирован в Qt6. Однако он работает только с компилятором MSVC.